# How to apply custom validation in Magento 2 checkout Shipping Address form?

Tags: magento-2.1, php, checkout, jquery, requirejs

In Magento2 - I want to apply some custom validation on shipping address form of Magento 2 Checkout. Normally I do it with JQuery but don't know how to apply it in Magento 2.

The validation I want to implement are mentioned below.

- Allow only alphabet on some field.
- Allow dash (-) , hash (#) , both slash (/ , ) and dot (.) in the address1 field
- Allow only digits in the ZIP field
- Allow only numbers in PhoneNumber field
- Set Max length to 50 for First Name, Last Name and Company
- Set Max length to 5 Digits for Zip code.
- Set Max length to 20 for City
- Set Max length to 10 Digits for Phone Number.